# Prevent thread blocking queued threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I have a task that will run many times with different values. I'd like to prevent it from executing 2 of the same tasks (Based on the string value) at the same time. Below is an example of the strings. These values will change, but for simplicity I have included these values below in the example. I submit these tasks via an `ExecutorService` The tasks run, but the 2nd hi blocks the other tasks from running. So 4/5 tasks run concurrently. Once the lock is released from the first hi the 5th tasks continues and the other tasks continue fine. Is there a way to prevent this type of blocking of the task so that the other 3 tasks can run before it so there is no queuing until there is actually 5 tasks running concurrently.

Submission of the tasks:

```
executor.submit(new Task("hi"));
executor.submit(new Task("h"));
executor.submit(new Task("u"));
executor.submit(new Task("y"));
executor.submit(new Task("hi"));
executor.submit(new Task("p"));
executor.submit(new Task("o"));
executor.submit(new Task("bb"));
```

The Task is simple. It just prints out the string:

```
Lock l = getLock(x);
try {
l.lock();

System.out.println(x);

try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Task.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

} finally {
l.unlock();

}
```

I've updated the post to allow for things to be more clearly understood...

Comment: There’s no sense in creating new threads manually, only to call `executor.submit(…);` The purpose of `submit` is to execute the task according to the executor’s policy, e.g. to run the task in another thread of a thread pool. Wrapping the `submit` call in another thread is a waste of resources. Just execute the `submit` calls directy.

Comment: @Holger new threads will be coming in randomly from clients. This was to simulate that.

Comment: Don’t use the word “thread” when you mean “task” or “job”. You don’t not submit threads to an executor, you submit `Runnable`s which encapsulate a task. The `executor` decides how to map the tasks to threads. The caller thread of the `submit` call is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger Is a task not on a separate thread...? I'm unsure how this is even relevant towards my question?

Comment: It depends on the particular executor, how each job maps to a thread. You entire question is based on the assumption that *not* every task gets a separate thread but that there are *less* threads than tasks (otherwise, there would be no problem in blocking threads). This is indeed not the most important aspect of the question, but using the right terms may be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Holger if it seems as though I am making that assumption. It is simply because I don't know how to explain the issue myself. Did my edit explain it better?

Comment: Yes, that’s better. I hope, the answer helps you. Let me know if there’s still a problem.

Comment: @Holger it helped me and I have already implemented the ideas into my project. I thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid blocking a thread, you have to ensure that the action doesn’t even run before the other. For example, you can use a `CompletableFuture` to chain an action, to be scheduled when the previous has been completed:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) submit("one", task("one"), es);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) submit("two", task("two"), es);
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(26));
    es.shutdown();
}

static Runnable task(String x) {
    return () -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));
    };
}

static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<Void>> MAP
    = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

static final void submit(String key, Runnable task, Executor e) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> job = MAP.compute(key,
        (k, previous) -> previous != null?
            previous.thenRunAsync(task, e): CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, e));
    job.whenComplete((v,t) -> MAP.remove(key, job));
}
```

The `ConcurrentHashMap` allows us to handle the cases as atomic updates

- If no previous future exists for a key, just schedule the action, creating the future
- If a previous future exists, chain the action, to be scheduled when the previous completed; the dependent action becomes the new future
- If a job completed, the two-arg `remove(key, job)` will remove it if and only if it is still the current job

The example in the `main` method demonstrates how two independent actions can run with a thread pool of two threads, never blocking at thread.

Comment: Beautiful. I had tried something similar to this, but wasn't using the `ConcurrentHashMap` I will definitely do some more reading on this.